# Is there any 3d model viewer for reactJS

Tags: reactjs, 3d, revit

I've been trying to find a good 3d model viewer for reactjs to render .rcs or .rcp files exported through revit and allows the user to rotate and adjust the model to a certain point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Forge Viewer](http://developer.autodesk.com), which uses JavaScript and can be embedded into any webapp via `<div>`, you can find an example [here](http://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io).

It supports `.rcp`, but you can use direct `.rvt` models, which is better as you can see the metadata. [See complete list](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/overview/supported-translations/). Note the WebGL/Three.js viewable is extracted, so an end-user cannot access the seed file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try an Open Source viewer from TT Core team: http://core.thorntontomasetti.com/apps/Spectacles/

Since it's free and Open Source it sure has some limitations and is not being developed as dynamically as the Forge viewer mentioned above, but it's a nice alternative if you don't want to spend a fortune on Autodesk Tokens.